# MYSQL SELECT 2 Condition Status

Tags: mysql

Tables `HrAttLogs` :

```
| Id    | MachineIp   | FingerId | Date       | Time     | Status | Verified | DateCreated         |
| ----- | ----------- | -------- | ---------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | ------------------- |
| 254   | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-21 | 08:18:03 | 0      | 1        | 2020-04-22 14:46:21 |
| 64    | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-22 | 07:57:08 | 0      | 1        | 2020-04-22 14:46:21 |
| 14470 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-23 | 08:05:15 | 0      | 1        | 2020-04-23 08:39:23 |
| 14991 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-23 | 15:27:06 | 1      | 1        | 2020-04-25 11:00:17 |
| 14972 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-23 | 16:24:53 | 1      | 1        | 2020-04-25 11:00:16 |
| 14842 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-24 | 08:46:21 | 0      | 1        | 2020-04-25 11:00:16 |
| 14764 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-24 | 15:31:57 | 1      | 1        | 2020-04-25 11:00:15 |
| 16222 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-27 | 17:29:13 | 1      | 1        | 2020-05-02 09:05:05 |
| 16103 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-28 | 08:50:55 | 0      | 1        | 2020-05-02 09:05:04 |
| 16024 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-28 | 16:42:14 | 1      | 1        | 2020-05-02 09:05:04 |
| 15894 | 10.20.20.73 | 10       | 2020-04-29 | 09:43:38 | 0      | 1        | 2020-05-02 09:05:03 |
```

I have a case in my Query, where in the `HrAttLogs` table data for date `2020-04-27` only has 1 record with `Status = 1`. Because in the next query the selected data has a filter `WHERE Status ! = 1`. How do to `SELECT` the 1 record which only has `Status = 1` like record on date `2020-04-27` ?

Result Query :

```
| FingerId | Status_Logs | ShiftId | Date       | DateOut    | Time     |
| -------- | ----------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-21 | 2020-04-21 | 08:18:03 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-22 | 2020-04-22 | 07:57:08 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-23 | 2020-04-23 | 08:05:15 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-24 | 2020-04-24 | 08:46:21 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-28 | 2020-04-28 | 08:50:55 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-29 | 2020-04-29 | 09:43:38 |
```

What I need from the results is displays 1 record with conditions like the one above which has `Status = 1` but does not have `Status = 0` with results :

```
| FingerId | Status_Logs | ShiftId | Date       | DateOut    | Time     |
| -------- | ----------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-21 | 2020-04-21 | 08:18:03 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-22 | 2020-04-22 | 07:57:08 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-23 | 2020-04-23 | 08:05:15 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-24 | 2020-04-24 | 08:46:21 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | -          | 2020-04-27 | -        |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-28 | 2020-04-28 | 08:50:55 |
| 10       | 0           | 1       | 2020-04-29 | 2020-04-29 | 09:43:38 |
```

I have an existing query like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kqWFdA6uUcby4XvdaQL9vp/0), the problem with that query is that I have not been able to display the output expected by me.

**[UPDATE]**
This was resolved with the answers I marked correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
    i.FingerId,
    i.Status AS 'Status_Logs',
    fs.ShiftId,
    CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 THEN
        MIN(i.Date)
    END AS 'Date',
    CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 AND MIN(i.Time) >= '19:00:00' 
         THEN DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + 1 DAY)) 
    ELSE 
        DATE(DATE_ADD(i.Date, INTERVAL + s.DayOut DAY)) 
    END AS 'DateOut',
    CASE WHEN i.Status = 0 THEN
        i.Time
    END AS 'Time'
    FROM HrAttLogs AS i
    INNER JOIN HrEmployee AS fs ON fs.FingerId = i.FingerId
    INNER JOIN HrEmployeeShift AS s ON s.Id = fs.ShiftId
    WHERE 
            i.Time >= s.ShiftIn_1
            AND i.Date >= '2020-04-21'
            AND i.Date <= '2020-05-10' 
            AND i.MachineIp = '10.20.20.73'
            AND i.FingerId = 10
            AND i.Status != 1
    GROUP BY
            i.Date
UNION
SELECT 
    i.FingerId,
    j.Status AS 'Status_Logs',
    fs.ShiftId,
    NULL AS 'Date',
    i.Date AS 'DateOut',
    NULL AS 'Time'
    FROM HrAttLogs AS i
    LEFT JOIN HrAttLogs j ON j.Date = i.Date AND j.Status != 1
    INNER JOIN HrEmployee AS fs ON fs.FingerId = i.FingerId
    WHERE 
        i.Status = 1
        AND j.Id IS NULL
    ORDER BY
        DateOut ASC;
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, welcome to Stack!  Best practice is to include a description of what your code is doing, with relation to the OP's question rather than just posting a code snippet with out an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of ways to do this. Here's one:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,date DATE NOT NULL
,status TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(  254,'2020-04-21',0),
(   64,'2020-04-22',0),
(14470,'2020-04-23',0),
(14991,'2020-04-23',1),
(14972,'2020-04-23',1),
(14842,'2020-04-24',0),
(14764,'2020-04-24',1),
(16222,'2020-04-27',1),
(16103,'2020-04-28',0),
(16024,'2020-04-28',1),
(15894,'2020-04-29',0);

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date = x.date 
   AND y.status = 0 
 WHERE x.status = 1 
   AND y.id IS NULL;
+-------+------------+--------+
| id    | date       | status |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 16222 | 2020-04-27 |      1 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```